# 'Stage' cannot be used as a JSX component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, 2d, pixi.js

Just began learning **PixiJS** and created a react app following **[tutorial](https://pixijs.io/pixi-react/)** instructions.

Copied and pasted following **[code](https://pixijs.io/pixi-react/#usage)** didn't let me start the project due to the error in `<Stage>` component with following text:

```
'Stage' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its type 'typeof Stage' is not a valid JSX element type.
    Type 'typeof Stage' is not assignable to type 'new (props: any, deprecatedLegacyContext?: any) => Component<any, any, any>'.
      Type 'Stage' is missing the following properties from type 'Component<any, any, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.ts(2786)
```

I read that probably it means that `<Stage>` cannot be a root component so it has to be wrapped into **React.Fragment**. I did it but the problem still remains due to which I cannot continue my learning

### Full Code

```js
"use client";

import { BlurFilter } from "pixi.js";
import { Stage, Container, Sprite, Text } from "@pixi/react";
import { useMemo } from "react";

export default function Home() {
    const blurFilter = useMemo(() => new BlurFilter(4), []);

    return (
        <>
            <Stage>
                <Sprite
                    image="https://pixijs.io/pixi-react/img/bunny.png"
                    x={400}
                    y={270}
                    anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
                />

                <Container x={400} y={330}>
                    <Text
                        text="Hello World"
                        anchor={{ x: 0.5, y: 0.5 }}
                        filters={[blurFilter]}
                    />
                </Container>
            </Stage>
        </>
    );
}
```